# company's Database Table Structure and logic

Tags: mysql, database

First i would like to apologies if the title of the question is improper.

am working on a job portal with a little of linkedin in it,
am finding it difficult to make a structure for the companies table, cus i do not want their contact like mail, phone number and address to be in same table has the company's name and description.

i would be glad if any one can help me make sense of a beta way to deal with this issue.

Comment: is there any particular reason to split the data in two (or more) tables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @VedranJukic yes, for companies with multiple branches

Comment: you could create `companies` table and lets say `branches` table where `branches` would have `companyId` foreign key field. that way you will create master/detail relationship that will enable you to have multiple branches for each company.

Comment: this is just a simple explanation, but exploring  master/detail relation concept will probably be what you are looking for

Comment: @vedranjukic let me try that